# Benifits of using Breadboard instead of PCB

Tags: pcb, breadboard

What are the main advantages of using breadboard instead of PCB?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Works great for quick prototypes using through-hole resistors, capacitors, and DIPs with 22ga solid-core copper wire.

You need to be aware of the *disadvantages* though.

- not meant for withstanding high voltages (don't plan on anything above 48V)
- not meant for carrying high currents (I'd consider anything over 20mA questionable and anything over 100mA objectionable)
- high parasitic inductance and resistance
- high parasitic capacitance between adjacent rows

The last two are issues with high bandwidth circuits; don't expect to send around 10MHz analog signals easily. One way of getting around it a little bit is for sensitive signals to use every other row and ground the in-between rows. (this is somewhat like using a guard ring) This also works well for reducing unwanted Miller capacitance e.g. between base and collector pins of a bipolar transistor.

Answer (score 11):

You can re-use breadboard and move components/connections around to try different things.

That's about it really.  Flexibility to experiment.

Answer (score 6):

- It is reusable.
- This makes it easy to use for creating temporary prototypes and
  experimenting with circuit design.
- A variety of electronic systems may be prototyped by using
  breadboards, from small analog and digital circuits to complete
  central processing units (CPUs).
- These are typically high-quality breadboard modules mounted on a flat casing.
- The casing contains additional equipment for breadboarding, such as a
  power supply, one or more signal generators, serial interfaces, LED
  or LCD modules, and logic probes.